# How to create a complete c# program that will simulate stack operations

Tags: c#, stack

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
namespace stack

    public class Stack :IEnumerable<int> {
        private int size;
        private int[] stackArray;
        private int top = -1;
    
        public int Count { get { return top +1;}}
    
        public Stack(int size){
            this.size = size;
            stackArray = new int[size];
        }
    
         public void Push(int item){
            if ((top+1) ==  size)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref stackArray, ++size);
            }
            top++;
            stackArray[top]= item;
        }
        public int Pop()
        {
            int value = stackArray[top];
            top--;
            return value;
        }
    
        public int Peek()
        {
            return stackArray[top];
        }
    
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator(){
            for(int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
            {
                yield return stackArray[i];
            }
        }
    
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        
        }

}
```

I don't know what's wrong in my code. Everytime I run the code, it always shows "Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings"
It supposed to implement stacks but I do not know what went wrong. I'm just a begginer so please bear with me.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPpTi.png)

Comment: Show a screenshot of this "Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings" plus a good amount of the screen around it, please. The c# compiler never just says "1 error" without telling you what it is, so I need to know why you cannot see it - always include full error messages when asking for help on the internet. Never simply say "I got an error"

Comment: (The only compile error I get on that code, after having put {} for namespace, is "does not contain a Main" which would be entirely reasonable for a class like this)

Comment: Two suggestions: Install [Visual Studio community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) as it actually tells you what the errors are, and consider using [Stack<int>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0) rather than implementing your own